Can't ping two application over a single TUN interface
I have two applications App_1 & App_2 on my machine 1 (Ubuntu 22.04) and just one TUN interface.
Each application works on IPV6 protocol and is able to ping another computer(App_3) on the same ipv6 network:
Issue : When i try to ping  the two application (App_1 & App_2) eachother via the single tun interface i receive an icmp_redirect message.

ping App_1 <-> App_3 : ok
ping App_2 <-> App_3 : ok
ping App_1 <-> App_2 : Not ok  ! (receive an icmp_redirect)
on each machine:

net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
net.ipv6.conf.all.proxy_ndp=1

routes to each machine/tun seems ok.
Any idea to force icmpv6 packets via tun interface and avoid redirects messages. ?
